# A Gaming Journey in Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, steam

First off, I'm running:

Dell Inspiron 530
Intel E4800 Dual Core
NVIDIA GTX 660
4GB DDR2 667MHz RAM
WD 500GB HDD
750W Rocketfish PSU

With that being said, I have been tweaking and making changes for months now and I'm quite please with the performance.
I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with the SteamOS login and I'm using NVIDIA 361 Drivers with 367.25 actually installed according to X server. (Manually updated from 361)

Question 1: My videocard GPU doesn't seem to be processing anything. When I do/play something I.E. Borderlands 2 and it loads a few things requiring video and cpu to both process, it sends it through the processor. How can I route video through the GPU like I would be able to do with Windows drivers?

Question 2: How can I enable [PhysX](https://developer.nvidia.com/physx-sdk)?

Comment: How do you know that the GPU "doesn't seem to be processing anything"? The CPU being active at any point of a program  doesn't prevent the GPU from being active on behalf of that program at the same time. In fact, the CPU needs to send instructions to the GPU for the latter to know what to do. As for 2), please see https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/2s2wd7/so_what_is_the_story_with_physx_on_linux/.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: Okay lets go with the first question, GPU. When I pull the usage in terminal via nvidia-smi (I think that is it.) It doesn't show any substancial clocking or usage then when something graphically intense happens, is smoke, explosions and glass shards reflections, the gpu will not budge, my fps will shoot to like 2 or 3 then maybe a second later after all of the pieces have rendered, I shoot back to above fps. Additionally, when a lot os stuff is loading it will bog down to 1fps but after everything has loaded, it can handle graphic instensity at above 60 fps.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.